# Jekyll hosted on Github not rendering my css generated file

Tags: github, sass, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to host my jekyll static website at github pages and almost everything is working fine. I tried everything to make my CSS generated file (from SASS) to work. But could not do it.

My website is on this URL: http://pedromarins.github.io/

My github repo is here: https://github.com/pedromarins/pedromarins.github.io/

My `_config.yml` is setted up as

`baseurl:     ""`

and

```
url: "http://pedromarins.github.io"
```

also my sass folder is setted up as

```
sass:
  sass_dir: assets/_sass
  style: compressed
```

I can't see what is wrong. If someone could help and point what is wrong I appreciate!

**UPDATE 1 - 18h37 29-April-2017**

Installed ghpages gem. Now my Gemfile looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

gem 'jekyll'
gem 'github-pages'
gem "json", "2.0.2"

group :jekyll_plugins do
    gem 'jekyll-livereload'
end
```

Comment: does it render as expected locally?

Comment: Any errors in Settings/Github Pages?

Comment: @ashmaroli locally it is perfect. That's why I can't get it!

Comment: @marcanuy no errors there!

Comment: @PedroMarins try to upload the site again without plugins and with gh-pages gem

Comment: @marcanuy thanks for the tip for the gh-pages gem. Fixed a lot of small dependencies but not the css rendering yet. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it a problem with not having a front matter on the files? I didn't see one. Unfort I can't bundle install your stuff, it's failing.

Comment: @Christian the error was at the css folder, as the following answer solves!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some hours trying to make your site work I found a solution.

What I figured out was that Jekyll only looks for the `css` directory at root level, so in order to make your site to work properly you need to add the `css` directory at root level and place in there your `style.sass` file.

After that, the Jekyll build process will generate the `style.css` file in that directory, so you just need to include that file in the `head.html` partial.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

And your site will just work as expected, no css rendering problems at all, you can leave your sass dir as `assets/_sass` with no problem, that directory is just to tell the `css/style.sass` file that the sass `@imports` are found in there.

So you can reference them just like you are doing:

```
---
---
@import "layout"
@import "components/header"
@import "components/now"
...
```

Now, another workaround is to have your `style.sass` file in your `assets` folder, but not in the `css` folder, just leave it in the `assets` folder, and access it from your `head.html` partial as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css">
```

And it will work too.

Just remember to set the correct path for your other non-css assets like images, icons or fonts.